# Is there a program to manage movies and TV shows that supports mp4 tags?

Tags: software-recommendation, multimedia, media-manager, mp4

I'm looking for a media manager that will display and play movies and TV shows and will read data included in mp4 and m4v files.

So far I've looked at XBMC, Moovida and Boxee and all of these seem to keep their own separate database or XML files for reading and storing tag information. I also looked at Banshee because of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29513/tag-and-manage-video-files/29537#29537), but it didn't read my tags. Banshee is also geared towards music videos instead of actual movies and TV shows.

So I'm looking for software that

- Displays and plays movies and TV Shows
- Reads mp4 and m4v tags
- Preferably something with bulk import (i.e., I don't want to add 1,000 items to a new library)
- Bonus if it also has a tag editor
- Bonus if it's an XBMC extension

Comment: I have yet to find an mp4 tag editor of any worth in Ubuntu. I miss using mp3tag terribly (windows only tag editor). For the playing you've looked at VLC right? It can play and read the mp4 and import a folder.

Comment: @Chad--24216 I just looked at VLC for managing media. It's okay, although it doesn't seem to display artwork very well. It also isn't reading m4v files (although as far as I understand, changing the extension might work to solve that). You're right about tagging though. EasyTag is okay, but I've had issues. Honestly I've done most of my tagging on different platforms because there isn't much for Linux.

Comment: @Chat mp3tag runs fine on Wine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a program to do this on Linux.

There's a program called [AtomicParsley](http://atomicparsley.sourceforge.net/) which will tag your files in an iTunes style from the command line, but it doesn't have a GUI.

I tried writing my own program using AtomicParsley as a base for tagging, but it proved to be too risky. Tagging is at the byte level and minor changes can corrupt your files so that they're unplayable.

It's unfortunate for those who have large libraries coming from an iTunes setting, but there just isn't anything that will read and parse those files in a graphical setting.

Answer (score 0):

## XBMC

> **XBMC reads the Album Artist tag in ID3, Ogg, APE and MP4 tags** and uses it if available to assign an artist to the album (independently of the track's artist information). This is the "Album Artist" tag (in ID3 this is represented by the "TPE2" tag; in vorbiscomment (ogg) files "ALBUMARTIST", "ALBUM ARTIST" and "ENSEMBLE" are all supported). Multiple artists for either a track or album artist can be specified in "Artist1 / Artist2 / Artist3" format.

Source: http://wiki.xbmc.org/?title=Preparing_your_Music

Comment: This doesn't seem like it handles video files. The link you included only talks about audio files. From what I've read, XBMC will not read video tags. Can you show me how to get XBMC to read my tags? It certainly doesn't do it automatically, and I've messed with the settings and can't see anything that would do this.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I thought it did.