# How can I edit video tags?

Tags: video, vlc, tagging

I'm trying to edit the tags (title, artist, year etc) of a .mkv file with **VLC Player**. I open the video and select **Tools > Media information** (or ctrl+i). Then I do the changes I want and click in **Save metadata**. The tag seems to be changed only for the current VLC Player session, because when I open the mkv proprieties window, I can see it is not updated.

Is this a VLC Player bug? Can anyone help me with this issue? Or show me a way to edit the video tags. I searched for it and only found tag editors for MP3 and other audio formats.

Comment: Are you sure that this format supports tagging or that VLC can change the tags for that format?

Comment: VLC was reading the tags, so I assumed that it could write too. But it seems like it doesn't. I tried mkvproedit and worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've looked into this and it seems that editing mkv files isn't so straightforward. You might be interested in installing [mkvtoolnix](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/mkvtoolnix) package and giving a try to the [mkvpropedit](http://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/doc/mkvpropedit.html) command.

Comment: I've just seen a related question whose answers might be helpful [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/29513/5014).

Comment: mkvtoolnix-gtk is a graphical frontend to mkvtoolnix-cli, albeit more limited.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to change the general information in my IPTV playlist running VLC player and ran into the same problem.
I also have SMplayer installed. Loaded the playlist and made the desired change, then saved the file.
You can then open the VLC player reload the file and the new info is there.